# The method toArray is undefined for the type collection

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

[image]I am getting **the method toArray is undefined for the type collection** When I have multiple rows from the query. works fine when it has only one row.I am using Java 11.

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
        new EntityRespRowMapper());
```

This is my RowMapper class

```
public class EntityRespRowMapper implements RowMapper<EntityResponse>{

  @Override
  public EntityResponsemapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

    EntityResponse entity = new EntityResponse();

    entity.setEntity_id(rs.getLong("entity_id"));
    entity.setValue(rs.getString("value"));
    entity.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
    entity.setEnd_date(rs.getDate("end_date"));
    return entity ;
  }

}
```

What Am I doing wrong here. Can someone help me out. I tried QueryForList too.It gives the same issue.

Comment: Full stack trace please ;)

Comment: There is no stacktrace. I see this error in the response Object when I make a database call.

Comment: I just realized that your RowMapper class won't compile (explicit return at the end of the "constructor") - which I don't think is supposed to be a constructor

Comment: Do you mean that the `value` field of the `EntityResponse` object contains this string? Then it means it's what your database contains. If not, clarify. We can't see your screen. So you need to explain precisely what  you're doing, what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: Object response = jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
        new EntityRespRowMapper());   The response shows as Error in it.

Comment: *The response shows as Error in it* What does that mean. How do you display the object? How do you see this error? Be precise. Post the relevant code.

Comment: @JBNizet I addded the image. I see that when I am in debug mode.

Comment: So that means that the debugger of your IDE has a bug, or doesn't support Java 11.

Comment: I am using STS 3.9.8 which supports java 11.

Comment: Where exactly are you using toArray()? The proper syntax is to pass an empty array as a parameter. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Then it has a bug. Submit an issue to Eclipse.

Comment: @NirupIyer I am not using toArray(). RowMapper may be using toArray() and throw  error when there are multiple rows.

Comment: Hi [santosh-kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7846098/santosh-kumar), this post is more than 9 months old but I don't like unanswered question.
The return of the **query** method is a **List** of whatever **class** awaited (in your case EntityResponse). So try to use to put the result in a *List<EntityResponse>*. How about **EntityResponse**?

Comment: similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77530043/eclipse-fails-to-display-collection-elements-in-debug-mode-with-error-message-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to upgrade your eclipse 2019-06 & above.

I faced similar issue even with eclipse 2019-03 (eclipse-jee-2019-03) which supports Java 11 by default. In debug mode, when tried to see content of an object it was not able to display the content.

upgrading to eclipse 2019-06 (with both Java 11.0.3 & 11.0.4) allowed to debug the Object's contents.

Latest STS also should have upgraded its eclipse (I did not try it, though).

Comment: Can anybody confirm that this problem does not exist any more with more recent versions of STS / eclipse? With my version the issue still exists [see]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77530043/eclipse-fails-to-display-collection-elements-in-debug-mode-with-error-message-t). Am I missing anything?

Comment: This post explains the behaviour and shows how to fix unwanted error messages. Look for ["show/hide logical structure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77530043/eclipse-fails-to-display-collection-elements-in-debug-mode-with-error-message-t)

Answer (score -2):

This is issue with OpenJDK11 not STS. If you change the version to OpenJDK8 or change compiler compatibility & build your project on OpenJDK 8; this error should be resolved.