# eclipse fails to display collection elements in debug mode with error message "The method toArray() is undefined for the type Collection___"

Tags: eclipse, debugging, collections, undefined, toarray

I experience problems when debugging in eclipse. Similar issues are described in a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754207/the-method-toarray-is-undefined-for-the-type-collection) from more than 4 years ago. It is reported to be solved by some more recent versions of eclipse (STS) but obviously not in my environment. Any suggestions please?

```
eclipse Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)
eclipse Build id: 20230907-1323

java version:
openjdk version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 20.0.2+9.1 (build 20.0.2+9-jvmci-23.0-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 20.0.2+9.1 (build 20.0.2+9-jvmci-23.0-b15, mixed mode, sharing)

os version: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.2715]

code:

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> range = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        range.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
    }
}
```

[image]

breakpoint at range.forEach(...)

**update**

for those who searched for the show/hide logical structure button that is referred to in the accepted answer from @marco casallas, here is a snapshot with the button marked red [image: show/hide logical structure button]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Eclipse 2023-09 with Java 17 or with Java 20 (I didn't try GraalVM). Do you see this for other Java VMs too? You might have a _Detail Formatter_ in the preferences _Java > Debug > Detail Formatters_ that might cause this.

Comment: No, no detail formatters are defined. Switched to current jdk 21.0.1 (non graalvm). Still the same issue.

Comment: Same behaviour with jdk 20.0.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a solution but I noticed and somewhere in the bug email (it seems this was present before) list over eclipse there is a comment mentioning that if you disable "show logical structure" (icon at the left of collapse all) it will let you see the contents of the object, I don't know what "logical structure" does but it worked for me to at least get a view of what was inside my variables
 [image  here since i don't have high rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GYxv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but I managed to get it working like before with the logical structure. Try pressing the "three dots" icon **View menu** right of the "show logical structure" icon on the **Variables view**, go to **Java > Java preferences**, then select **Logical Structures**, add a new type and fill:

- **Qualified type**: Browse for **java.util.ArrayList** in the jdk or jre that you project is using and select it.
- **Description**: Write any description for it.
- **Applies to subtypes**: should be marked.
- **Structure type**: single value.
- **Code**: `return toArray();`

Apply and close, it should be working now, at least for ArrayList objects, but I suspect that the same can be done to other List Objects and Maps.

My eclipse is version is 2024-03 (4.31.0) and my jdk is version 21.

This window can also be found in **window > Preferences > Java > Debug > Logical Structures**.